# Display of a Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have created a custom Visualforce page and controller. I would like to know how to visualize the page I created in the context of Salesforce environment. I would like to know how to open the page:
1. Is it possible to create url address and somehow to use it in order to open the page?
2. Is it possible to invoke the page by using apex source code. I looked in other sites and I found that it can be achieved but I did no find a way to make it work.
3. Is there some other approach or way to open the custom page?

Answer (score 1):

1. Manually editing your browser's URL to e.g. https://na15.salesforce.com/apex/YourPageName?id=003i000000QT3nr will display your page; you can append parameters such as the "id" one.
2. In your Apex code, the symbol `Page.YourPageName` creates a new [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm) each time you reference it and that can be returned from a controller action method (example shown in the PageReference link) to select the next page displayed.
3. If you have made your page an extension of a standard controller, you can hook your page in in place of the standard actions (via the object's "Buttons, Links, and Actions" section) like New or View or Edit. This is a good technique to use for custom objects where you always want your Visualforce page to be used and you undserstand all use cases; it is a bad technique to use for standard objects because the override applies to all users irrespective of their profile so you are impacting every user and every app.

**PS**

In response to the comment, this should do it (and has the benefit of being compile-time checked):

```
public PageReference ErrorMessage7() {
    return Page.ErrorMessagePage;
}
```

or if you had some string reason to want to use a string use this relative URL (which is portable to different orgs):

```
public PageReference ErrorMessage7() {
    return new PageReference('/apex/ErrorMessagePage');
}
```

If you want to add parameters (i.e. values appended in the `?` query string):

```
public PageReference ErrorMessage7() {
    PageReference pr = Page.ErrorMessagePage;
    pr.getParameters().put('id', ...);
    pr.getParameters().put('xyz', ...);
    return pr;
}
```

Comment: I created my own method 
public PageReference ErrorMessage7() {
     PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://c.cs42.visual.force.com/apex/ErrorMessagePage.vfp');
     return pr;    
    }
the way described in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm but still not able to see the open page. Could you please advise what else I need to do in order to visualize the page?